# How to generically execute Java object on a remove application?

Tags: java, serialization, network-programming

Firstly I don't think I phrased the question very well, however you'll understand why when you read the description.

I have two applications, one being a master application that takes tasks as input from the user, each task implements an interface Task that in-turn is serialisable.

```
public interface Task extends Callable, Serializable { ... }
```

Lets call the task classes that user gives it ImplementedTask (that implement the provided interface, Task).

When the user runs the master application, it saves the ImplementedTasks to some network storage (as serialised objects) and communicates with the second application (an agent on another machine) to execute the tasks. To do this, it needs to read in the objects and run the Call method, specified in the Task interface that each task implements.

To achieve this I have the following code:

```
try (FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(path);
                    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn)) {
                    Object ob = in.readObject();
                    tasks.put((Task) ob, path);
}
```

However when I try and read in the serialised task from the network storage, it errors with a ClassNotFound exception that it can't find the ImplementedTask class. This is correct, however I thought that because Task extends serialisable, this would work.

How can I dynamically let users implement the Task interface and have my agent be able to read in the implemented class on another machine?

Comment: If you mean "Do I need `ImplementedTask.class` on the path everywhere it is referenced, then the answer is "yes."  Serialization won't obviate the classpath, you still need the class file available to the receiver.

Comment: The problem about that is, when person B comes along they will make another implementation of the Task interface and therefore the class will be different, is there a way that I can make this object generically useable across applications? Or can I pass the ImplementedTask.class across to the second application (by saving it through serialisation or suchlike) which can then be identified in the second application and used to read in the serialised tasks?

Comment: Nope, there isn't.  You could use a classloader that loads classes from from some repository on the internet (Java applets do this) but as fair as I know that's not a standard feature.  I'd suggest you look in that direction -- search for a classloader that loads from some sort of dynamic library.  I can't think of any off the top of my head, I'm used to static deployments for everything.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269291/executing-a-class-file-sent-over-the-network-in-java  (answer "no").

Comment: Pitfalls of attempting to load classes: http://www.szegedi.org/articles/remotejars.html

Comment: rsync is your friend: http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/

Comment: If you've enough time for this project, check ***Java RMI***. That would solve your problem for sure.

Comment: The problem about using Java RMI is that my two applications are effectively a mini distributed system where tasks are presented to the Master that has to give the task to the agent over a network. Java RMI can only be used when both applications share the exact same classes and have programmatically been designed for that purpose (AFAIK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a work around that involves working out the class path at runtime on the master application of the implementation classes that are required to run the tasks. The classes are then copied over to the network storage where the serialisable tasks are stored and dynamically added to the class path of the agent on the other machine.